# combine two field value in single field anonymous type linq

Tags: linq, select, anonymous

0I want to perform the linq select query for getting the anonymous type field which is a concatenation of two fields.

```
(from c in ctx.Documents
where c.FileName == doc.FileName
select new
{
    fileName = c.FileName + "" + c.UploadDate,
    value = c.UploadDate
}).ToList();
```

but this linq query throws the exception

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
>   to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM
>   primitive or enumeration types.

please guide me to solve this error. I know that it is because of the concatenation of date with string but how do i resolve the isse and get the desired output.

Thanks,
Please reply fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
(from a in
(from c in ctx.Documents 
     where c.FileName == doc.FileName
     select c).AsEnumerable() 
     select new { fileName = a.FileName + "" + a.UploadDate, 
                  value = a.UploadDate }).ToList();
```

Comment: you are getting same exception?

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: It is throwing the same exception.

Comment: try: SqlFunctions.StringConvert(c.UploadDate)

Comment: or in that one try this:StringConvert((double)c.UploadDate)

Comment: the edited query gives compilation error " A query or body must end with a select clause"

Comment: check the update i forgot to add select in the first part before making iEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  fileName = c.FileName == null ? String.Empty : c.FileName + c.UploadDate== null ? :   String.Empty : c.UploadDate ;
```